# No module named compressor

Tags: python

Ребят помогите исправить ошибку. На винде пытаюсь запустить сервер на вин10, а мне пишет No module named compressor, ниже код терминала.

```
python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x0000000005AD3588>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\dev\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\dev\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "E:\dev\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "E:\dev\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\dev\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "E:\dev\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "E:\dev\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named compressor

(venv) E:\dev\shop\manka>pip install django_compressor
Collecting django_compressor
  Downloading django_compressor-2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118kB)
    100% |################################| 122kB 380kB/s
Collecting rjsmin==1.0.12 (from django_compressor)
  Using cached rjsmin-1.0.12.tar.gz
Collecting rcssmin==1.0.6 (from django_compressor)
  Using cached rcssmin-1.0.6.tar.gz
Collecting django-appconf>=1.0 (from django_compressor)
  Using cached django_appconf-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: rjsmin, rcssmin
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rjsmin ... error
  Complete output from command e:\dev\shop\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kirill\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bvdfga\\rjsmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\kirill\appdata\local\temp\tmpszlr0fpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  copying .\rjsmin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_rjsmin' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for rjsmin
  Running setup.py clean for rjsmin
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for rcssmin ... error
  Complete output from command e:\dev\shop\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kirill\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bvdfga\\rcssmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\kirill\appdata\local\temp\tmpxp5jbbpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  copying .\rcssmin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
  running build_ext
  building '_rcssmin' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for rcssmin
  Running setup.py clean for rcssmin
Failed to build rjsmin rcssmin
Installing collected packages: rjsmin, rcssmin, django-appconf, django-compressor
  Running setup.py install for rjsmin ... error
    Complete output from command e:\dev\shop\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kirill\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bvdfga\\rjsmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kirill\appdata\local\temp\pip-oybuvy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers e:\dev\shop\venv\include\site\python2.7\rjsmin:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    copying .\rjsmin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    running build_ext
    building '_rjsmin' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

    ----------------------------------------
Command "e:\dev\shop\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\kirill\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bvdfga\\rjsmin\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\kirill\appdata\local\temp\pip-oybuvy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers e:\dev\shop\venv\include\site\python2.7\rjsmin" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\kirill\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bvdfga\rjsmin\
```

Comment: Что непонятно в тексте ошибки? Пробовали выполнить то, что текст ошибки просит сделать?

Comment: я сделала pip install django_compressor и установила Microsoft Visual C++, но ошибка не ушла

Comment: спасибо) все решилось pip install rcssmin --install-option="--without-c-extensions"
pip install rjsmin --install-option="--without-c-extensions"
pip install django-compressor